# copying fields from multiple tables to create new table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to create a table by copying only the columns from multiple tables??

> eg. t1 with fields (A1,A2,A3)
>
> ```
> t2 with fiedls (D1,D2,D3)
>
> t3 with fields (Z1,Z2,Z3)
> ```

Now I've to create a new table **using only the fields not the values** from the above three tables i.e.

> new_tbl (A1,A2,A3,D1,D2,D3,Z1,Z2,Z3)

How can I do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
create table new_tbl as
select * 
from   t1
join   t1 on 1=2
join   t3 on 1=2
```

the condition 1=2 is always false.. so it will not return any data but the column header..

Comment: +1 could be simpler: `create table new_tbl as select * from t1, t2, t3 where 1=2`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp :you are true..  but I thought of avoiding commas and use the key word join